# Login as root with two different passwords

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords, root

Is it possible to login via ssh on a linux machine, using one of two (or more) passwords set for root? 
I want a primary password that I will change it frequently but in a case of emergency I want a "backup" password that will log me in. I hope that I stated the question clear. ;)

Comment: So why not create another backup account instead?

Comment: What kind of emergency are you trying to prevent? Simple 'loss-of-root-password' can be fixed, assuming you have access to the physical box, by booting into single-user mode.

Comment: This is non-sense. I suggest you learn how to use sudo, might help in your case.

Comment: I know, I wanted to grant access in case of emergency to a co-worker, but I didn't want to give him my password due to privacy reasons and frequently changes... Maybe I will try to make a account for him with the appropriate privileges.

Comment: In that case the sudo is best fit for your situation.

Comment: don't lure yourself into a false sense of security by frequently changing the password of one root account but not of the other. (and i'd suggest looking into sudo as well)

Answer (score 5):

Don't use root accout. Use [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo).

When you configure sudo for your ordinary account, you can change root password to something complex and use sudo for normal daily work.
When something breaks, you will login to root with the complex password.

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple accounts that have userid 0, each with a different password. What matters for permissions is the userid, not the name.

However, there are some scripts that may check whether you're running as root, and they might check the login name rather than the ID. But if you're just using the backup account for emergency purposes, these glitches should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the root login via ssh and create two user accounts, one for myself and a default account (which is there on all my machines with limited sudo access) with sudo access for both is what I do.

Comment: Thanks... Really fast reply... ;)

Answer (score 0):

If it's all about `ssh`, then you can use **keybased authentication**, rather than password based auth.
This way, two (or more) users can login (as root, as a given user) without having to share the password.

Comment: This.  Simple and secure.  Doing it the sudo way is ok but that's just one more step.  Not necessary when using keys imo.

Comment: @fred if you like the answer you should upvote it.